NoSuchMethodError when calling transceive on NFC tag in Flutter app
I'm developing a Flutter app that reads NFC tags using the nfc_manager package. I am encountering the following error when trying to read data from an NFC tag:
Error reading data: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Map<Object?, Object?>' has no instance method 'transceive'.
Receiver: _Map len:5
Tried calling: transceive(_Uint8List)

nfc_service.dart :
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/platform_tags.dart'; // Ensure this import is included

class NfcService {
  Future<String> readData(NfcTag tag) async {
    try {
      // Print the contents of tag.data for debugging
      print('!!!!!!!!!!!!! TAG DATA: ${tag.data}');

      // Extract NFC-A data from the tag
      final nfcaData = tag.data['nfca'];

      // Print the type and contents of nfcaData for debugging
      print('QQQQQQ nfcaData type: ${nfcaData.runtimeType}');
      print('MMMMMM nfcaData contents: $nfcaData');

      if (nfcaData != null) {
        // Create NfcA instance from the tag
        final nfca = NfcA.from(tag);

        // Check if nfca is not null
        if (nfca != null) {
          // Prepare the command to read data from the tag
          final command = Uint8List.fromList(
              [0x3A, 0x00, 0x01]); // Example command for reading

          // Call transceive method with the command
          final result = await nfca.transceive(data: command);

          // Print raw result for debugging
          print('Raw result (Uint8List): $result');

          // Attempt to decode the result using UTF-8
          String resultText;
          try {
            resultText = utf8.decode(result, allowMalformed: true);
          } catch (e) {
            resultText =
                'Failed to decode text: ${result.toString()}'; // Show raw result if decoding fails
          }

          return resultText;
        } else {
          return 'NfcA instance could not be created';
        }
      } else {
        return 'Unsupported NFC tag type or no NFC-A data';
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      print('SSSSSS Stack trace:\n$s');
      return 'Error reading data: $e';
    }
  }
}



scan_page.dart :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';
import 'package:soremar_inventory/services/nfc_service.dart';

class ScanTagPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScanTagPage({super.key});

  @override
  ScanTagPageState createState() => ScanTagPageState();
}

class ScanTagPageState extends State<ScanTagPage> {
  final NfcService _nfcService = NfcService();
  bool _isScanning = false;
  String _scanMessage =
      'Placez votre téléphone près de l\'étiquette NFC pour scanner.';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Controller un produit'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 48, 161),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Background GIF
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/scan.gif', // Ensure the path is correct
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          // Foreground content
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _startScan,
                  child: const Text('Cliquez ici pour scanner une tag NFC'),
                ),
                if (_isScanning) const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                Text(_scanMessage),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _startScan() async {
    if (_isScanning) return; // Prevent starting multiple scans

    setState(() {
      _isScanning = true;
      _scanMessage =
          'Placez votre téléphone près de l\'étiquette NFC pour scanner.';
    });

    try {
      await NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
        final data = await _nfcService.readData(tag);
        setState(() {
          _scanMessage = 'Data: $data';
        });
        _stopScan(); // Stop scan after reading data
      }).catchError((e) {
        setState(() {
          _scanMessage = 'Error: $e';
        });
        _stopScan(); // Ensure the session is stopped on error
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _scanMessage = 'Error: $e';
      });
      _stopScan(); // Ensure the session is stopped on error
    }
  }

  void _stopScan() {
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession().catchError((e) {
      print('Error stopping NFC session: $e');
    });
    setState(() {
      _isScanning = false;
    });
  }
}


tag.data is a map and it looks like the code is expecting nfca to be an instance of a class with a transceive method.
The error suggests that the map does not have a method named transceive.

It looks like you are not creating the nfca object correctly and thus cannot transceive to it.
if (tag.data.containsKey('nfca')) {
        var nfca = tag.data['nfca'];


should be
var nfca = NfcA.from(tag);
if (nfca != null) {
  Uint8List arrayOfByte = await nfca.transceive(
    data: Uint8List.fromList([0x30, 0x00]));
}



first of all, thank you for your answer, i tried what you said but it didn't work
i got the following errors

The named parameter 'data' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.


Updated normally in Android you need to name your parameters for transcieve but on flutter it seems you do, so updated and also added the correct return type.

i updated the code here, can u please take a look
